# How do I create an array with dynamic dimension sizes in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, multidimensional-array, dynamic-allocation

I'm looking to create an array (or vector?) to represent some files.

Basically, I'm going to have a variable number of input files. Each line of each file can be treated as a custom object (I'm calling them each a 'symbol'). There is a variable number of lines in each file.

So I'd like to have this kind of representation going on:

array[x][y]

where x will be referring to the file, and y the line in that file.

I'd seen a few topics on stackoverflow which suggested something along these lines

```
symbol **snapShots = new symbol*[usableFiles];
for(int i = 0; i < usableFiles; ++i) {
   snapShots[i] = new symbol[longestFile];
}
```

which is giving me an odd error message when building:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
   "symbol::symbol()", referenced from:
       _main in MarketDataGenerator.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Info: Parallel threads used: 3
```

Any ideas how I'd go about this? Or would I just be better storing the information in file temporarily before reading back in for further processing?

Comment: That error specifically probably means you haven't defined your default constructor, or didn't link to the definition. Anyway, use `std::vector`, not double pointers.

Comment: Would that include an undefined destructor? I'm pretty sure my constructor is ok.

Comment: It's complaining about the constructor in the error. It needs a body that the linker can find.

Comment: D'oh - Yeah missing default constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you considered using `std::vector<symbol>` or `std::vector<std::vector<symbol> >`? What you linker is trying to tell you, is that you have declared a default constructor for your class `symbol` but not defined it (at least not in the files you are linking).

Comment: Yeah - missing default constructor. Not sure how I overlooked that one! Anyway, thanks!